# MVC Open File without knowing the exact network drive

Tags: c#, windows, model-view-controller

In my MVC application, the logged in user is able to get data from a file they selected from a list of thousands of records.

All of the files are stored in the same folder name, but the network drive the user mapped these folders to may be different for everyone.

For instance, I have the folders mapped to "K:/Folder1/Subfolder/filename.txt" but another user may have the folders mapped to "L:/Folder1/Subfolder/filename.txt"

The Folder1/Subfolder/Filename.txt portion of the path is constant for every user, but the network drive will change.

Is there a way to access a file in a network drive without using the mapped letter (K: or L:) but instead using the actual folder name of the mapped network? (In my case, K: and L: or whatever letter that the user chose are all mapping to the same folder serverName//Archive/ ... )

In the left panel of File Explorer, the mapped drive looks like: "Archive (\wsafg01) (K:)" or "Archive (\wsafg01) (L:)" etc.

Essentially, I want to be able to open a file by this path: "serverName//Archive/Folder1/Subfolder/filename.txt" instead of "K:/Folder1/Subfolder/filename.txt", since the first option is the same for every user. When I try to do this the file is not found and I get an error. Is there a certain way to format an open file call to a network drive without using the mapped drive letter but the actual file path?

I can open the files on my computer if I use the path "K:/Folder1/Subfolder/filename.txt" so I figure there has to be a way to do it without calling the mapped drive first, but the actual folder.

Comment: If you're using UNC paths, shouldn't it be something like "\\serverName\Archive\Folder1\Subfolder\filename.txt"? I've never seen a path like "serverName//Archive/..." before.

Comment: "How to specify path to file on server" (which seem to be the question) may be on-topic on [superuser.se] (also likely duplicate). For this question to be on-topic here please provide reasonable [MCVE] showing code you have and errors you are getting.

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean "MVC application" - WPF *apps* usually use MVVM, questions about ASP.Net *sites* should be tagged "asp.net MVC". There is a significant differences between problems you going to hit between client and server cases.

Comment: Could you add tags for the type of project you're working on? As mentioned above, the solution may be slightly more involved for something such as an ASP.NET site, or a WPF app. The current tags/wording are a bit too vague as-is. MVC is just a pattern. It's not the type of application you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorta just spinning off my comment, but if you want to reference a path by server instead of mapped letter, the proper way to format that path (UNC) is like:

```
\\serverName\Archive\Folder1\Subfolder\filename.txt
```

Not the double backslash *before* the server name, and the usage of backslashes rather than forward slashes for Windows paths.

Comment: I assume you know that it will not really help OP with they presumably ASP.Net site... Please make sure to explain what needs to be done to support access to network shares from ASP.Net.

Comment: Wow, that was a very simple answer that I definitely should have realized on my own, but it worked! I am not sure why, but in ASP.NET when opening a file you can use either "\\\\serverName\\Archive\\Folder1\\Subfolder\\filename.txt " OR //serverName/Archive/Folder1/Subfolder/filename.txt